# How to specify the type of a vector of fixed size?

Tags: haskell, haskell-vector

I am trying to use [`Data.Vector.Fixed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-vector-1.2.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Fixed.html) as the input to a function and am struggling to specify the vector's dimension in the type signature.

For example, I am trying to do something like the following:

```
acronym :: Vector (Peano 8) String -> String
acronym = foldl1 (++)
```

and thus specifying the vector's dimension (8) using peano numbers as defined in [`Data.Vector.Fixed.Cont`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-vector-1.2.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Fixed-Cont.html#t:PeanoNum).

However, attempting to compile this gives kind-mismatch errors:

```
...:12: error:
    * Expected a type, but
      `Vector (Peano 8) String' has kind
      `Constraint'
    * In the type signature:
        acronym :: Vector (Peano 8) String -> String
   |
61 | acronym :: Vector (Peano 8) String -> String
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

...:20: error:
    * Expected kind `* -> *', but `Peano 8' has kind `PeanoNum'
    * In the first argument of `Vector', namely `(Peano 8)'
      In the type signature: acronym :: Vector (Peano 8) String -> String
   |
61 | acronym :: Vector (Peano 8) String -> String
```

How can I specify a fixed vector's size in a type signature?

Comment: `Vector` is not a type, it's a type class

Comment: I guess you are looking for [`Vec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-vector-1.2.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Fixed-Boxed.html#t:Vec) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, FlexibleContexts, GADTs #-}
import qualified Data.Vector.Fixed as V
acronym :: (V.Vector v String, V.Dim v ~ 8) => v String -> String
acronym = V.foldl1 (++)
```

The type class constraint `Vector v String` indicates that `v` is a vector with elements of type `String`, while the constraint `Dim v ~ 8` ensures it has the right size.

It can be used with specific vector types, like boxed or continuation vectors, like so:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Fixed.Boxed as BV
import qualified Data.Vector.Fixed.Cont as CV
eight = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight"]
main = do
  print $ acronym (V.fromList eight :: BV.Vec 8 String)
  print $ acronym (V.fromList eight :: CV.ContVec 8 String)
```